# execute MySQL init command using environment variables to create database

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I'm trying to create a database if it does not exist and set privledges but I'm having trouble getting it to work, I keep getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1`

I've included the various ways I've tried to execute the commands

Yaml:

```
  initContainers:
  - name: database-setup
    image: mysql:5.7
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    # command:  ["rm", "-fr", "/var/lib/mysql/lost+found"]
    # SQL Syntax error:
    command: [sh,-c,mysql -h mysql-service -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$WORDPRESS_DB_NAME` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME.* TO '$WORDPRESS_DB_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"]

      # Enviroment Variables arn't passed into mysql shell:
      # - sh
      # - -c
      # - mysql -h mysql-service -p$MYSQL_ROT_PASSWORD
      # - CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
      # - GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME.* TO '$WORDPRESS_DB_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD';
      # - FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
      # - EXIT;

      # SQL Syntax error:
      # - sh
      # - -c
      # - mysql -h mysql-service -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$WORDPRESS_DB_NAME` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME.* TO '$WORDPRESS_DB_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

    env:
    - name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
      value: wordpress-green
    - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
      value: wordpress-green
    - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: wordpress-mysql-pass
          key: wordpress-mysql-pass
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: mysql-root-pass
          key: mysql-root-pass
```

Comment: When you said "Enviroment Variables arn't passed into mysql shell" did you mean this literally?  Because this is a likely candidate for why that `CREATE DATABASE` statement is failing.

Comment: That block that I tried has that problem only the other two get the SQL syntax errors, it creates a database: $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME.

If I run the commands outside of a container and substitute the values it works.

Comment: I don't know enough about Kubernetes to help.  Look into that environment variable and why perhaps it isn't being set.

Comment: If I print all the variables outside of mysql in the same container, it works. `-e " "` does use the environment variables too.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but could you try just doing an `echo` for each line in your MySQL script?  Try to see exactly what is being run here.

Comment: why didn't I think of that... `mysql -h mysql-service -p\\REDACTED\\ -e CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress-green.* TO 'wordpress-green'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '\\REDACTED\\'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: So your parameters are not being bound.  Wish I knew how to fix that.  But the good news is, I'll bet you do :-)

Comment: Okay, I fixed the $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME  not being passed to the create DB sting by removing the \``, but it does not like the name wordpress-green?

Comment: Maybe MySQL does not like hyphens in DB/table/column names.  Try putting `wordpress-green` in backticks; but actually, just removing the hyphen is probably a better solution.

Comment: yep, backticks caused the inital problem, I'll just use camelCase instead

Comment: I think underscores would also be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried doing an `echo` for the MySQL line to debug the variables
returned:

```
mysql -h mysql-service -p\\REDACTED\\ -e CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress-green.* TO 'wordpress-green'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '\\REDACTED\\'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I fixed the $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME not being passed to the create DB sting by removing the `` - this caused SQL Syntax error again because it does not like a dash in the database name.
Instead I just used camelCase for the database name

Thanks for the help @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but I wished to use the hyphen in the database name (because this is valid syntax for Kubernetes resources naming). This is what worked for me

```yaml
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - mysql --host=$MYSQL_HOST --port=$MYSQL_PORT --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PWD
          --execute="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \"$WORDPRESS_DB_NAME\";"
```